# How to call custom function from postgresql use objection js knex js

Tags: node.js, objection.js, knex.js

I build api use hapi js and postgresql with ORM objection js (knexjs). I create own function in postgresql with two argument. When I try to call my function use objection `.raw` it's doesn't work. This one of the codes that I have tried and it doesn't work:

```
let _data = await Model.knex().raw('select * from fn_user_profiling('+ Model.knex().raw('??', ['840018']).toString() +', ' + Model.knex().raw('??', ['human capital']).toString() + ')');
```

This the error when I run the code:

```
select * from fn_user_profiling("840018", "human capital") - column "840018" does not exist
```

I try to follow this thred in [this link](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1565), but not work for me.

I hope advance can help to give the answer or clue to solve this problems.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `840018` is your column name or value

Comment: Value for my first argument in postgresql function.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I use objection js to call knex raw.

```
let _data = await Model.knex().raw('select * from function_name(?, ?)', [arg_1, arg_2]);
```

I hope this can help someone.

Comment: Used your solution. got this. `calling knex without a tableName is deprecated. Use knex.queryBuilder() instead.
(node:18) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: databaseProvider.knex(...).raw is not a function`